# Pygame cant find a picture

Tags: python, image, pygame

my problem is that pygame cant find my picture (bg.png)

```
class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)  #call Sprite initializer
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location
BackGround = Background ('bg.PNG', [0, 0] )
```

Comment: Try adding full path.and pls also mention what is the error..

Comment: like what. can you give an exmple

Comment: Example: `BackGround = Background ('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Folder\\bg.PNG', [0, 0] )`

Answer (score 0):

The image filepath has to be relative to the current working directory. The working directory is possibly different to the directory of the python file.

The name and path of the file can be get by [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-related-module-attributes). The current working directory can be get by [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) and can be changed by [`os.chdir(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).

One solution is to change the working directory:

```py
import os

sourceFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(sourceFileDir)
```

An alternative solution is to find the absolute path.
If the image is relative to the folder of the python file (or even in the same folder), then you can get the directory of the file and concatenate the image filename. e.g.:

```py
import pygame
import os

# get the directory of this file
sourceFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# [...]

class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)  #call Sprite initializer
        
        imgPath = os.path.join(sourceFileDir, image_file)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(imgPath)
        
        # [...]
```

Comment: the program says i have syntax error

Comment: @swiflebot Sorry, but I can't neither see your code nor the error trace. The code in the answer  is syntactically correct.